# How to create custom warning in Eclipse for a standard Java API

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings

I want Eclipse to warn the use the of old Date/Calendar API in my Java project, allowing only the Java 8 brand new `Date-Time API` as the one beeing used in the source.

**How can I configure Eclipse to display a warning if, for example, `java.util.Date` is used?**

I happly accept additional comments on this approach, as well for other alternatives. I am aware that I should also apply this type of validation in the CI build, as well that Java Policy might be another alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an *access rule* for your project that causes Eclipse to show a warning when a certain class is used. *Right-click on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries*. Expand the *JRE System Library* (since your target class is `java.util.Date`) and select *Access rules*, then click on *Edit*.

[image]

In the shown dialog, click *Add* and fill in the resolution (e.g. Discouraged would generate a warning) and the pattern to match. In your case, the pattern is `java/util/Date`.

Another alternative is to write custom annotations and use the Java annotation processing API ([JSR269](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269)) to process them to generate a warning. But that would require you to annotate all the places in the code where you use that class.